# N-dimentional Array Broadcasting

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, broadcasting

Suppose I have some numpy array of 2 dimensions that I wish to broadcast to the center of a larger numpy array with some padding. I can use:

```
_large_array[1:-1, 1:-1] = _small_array
```

How do I extend this to the N dimensional case, where the dimension is an input? ie.

```
_large_n_array[1:-1, 1:-1, 1:-1,... ] = _small_array
```

Many thanks!

Comment: You need to specify all dimensions.

Comment: Maybe try something like `_large_n_array[[slice(1,-1) for _ in range(_large_n_array.ndim)]]` if `N` is `_large_n_array.ndim`